# Regex to match from the last appearance of a character, to the firts appearance of another one, not including either

Tags: regex

Basically I need to find a regex that matches the content between two characters:

//Whatev?er?
Shoud match "Whatev"

Ive tried a lot of regex expressions, none work. Any ideas?

Comment: In your example, do you mean to match "er" as it's between the two question marks? What happens if there are 3 question marks?

Comment: No, just match whatev. The idea would be to match everything between the last "/" and the first "?"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to match all text between two delimiters.

Let's say our delimiter is "%". You can look for the delimiter character, then match every character which is not said delimiter, and then the final delimiter. E.g.

`/%([^%]+)%/`

If you want to use two characters, a 'start' and an 'end', you can do: `/%([^#]+)#/` where '%' is the start and '#' is the end.

Per your comment, you'd do (escaping the slash and question mark where necessary):

`/\/([^?]+)\?/`

Comment: Thanks! Now, how would you do to limit the match to the first of two identical characters, for example here: //hi??, How would you match "hi" instead of "/hi?"

Comment: My example already does that. There's only one '?' in the pattern which must be preceded by a non-'?' character.

Comment: Wait, got it: /\/([^?]+)(?=\?). Thanks a lot!!

Comment: But that pattern won't match "//hello?" only "//hello??". Is that what you wanted? In that case I wouldn't use the lookahead, I'd just use: `\/\/([^?]+)\?\?`.

Answer (score 0):

`between the last "/" and the first "?"` [past last /]

would be

without assertions: `/([^/?]*)\?[^/]*$` result in capture group 1
with assertions: `(?<=/)[^/?]*(?=\?[^/]*$)` result is group 0

---

Example match:

> /asdf?/asdf/`asdf`?asdf?asdf

Example no match:

> /asdf?/asdf/asdf?asdf?a/sdf